# Audit and error handling in SSIS

Tags: error-handling, ssis, audit

We are starting a project to handle big, big flat files. These files are kind of 'normalized' and we want to process them first to an intermediate file.

I would like to see a custom table for audit rows and a custom table for errors that are thrown during processing. Also errors must be stored in the Event Log.

What are the best practices according to audit & error handling in general for SSIS (VS2008)?

**(edit)**
We have made (I think) very elegant solution by designing 1 master package. This package runs a child package (the one orginally intended). The master package subscribes to the 3 events like OnInformation, OnWarning and OnError. These events are routed to a generic audit & logging service that makes calls to the Enterprise Library Logging & Exception handling blocks.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend you is to adopt the following philosophy for stable etl processes coming from files:

1. Never cast anything in the connector, just import the fields as nvarchars of the maximum lenght they will achieve.
2. Procedurally add a rowcount for error tracking in casting errors.
3. Cast and control each column to your specification.
4. If a row cannot be read at some stage, you will not know the index, but you will know that the file is malformed (extremely rare in my experience, for half transferred files), and it should be rejected anyway.

A quick screenshot of a part of a file loading process shows how the rejection (after assigning row_id) can work ([link to dataflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB5hc.png)). To this you can add further countless checks (duplicates...) and even have a repository for the loaded files to check upon the rejects and whatever else you might want to control ([Link to control flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5zRb.png)).

In some of my processes, I even use a flat file connector and just import each row as a bulk text and then split it in columns with an intermediate script component, allowing for  different versions of the columns in the files.

Anyway, sorry not to be more detailed (due to my status I can't add more links or any images), but I hope that you understand the concept.

Regards,

Francisco.